# Magento -- "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation.." on customer update

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, mysql-error-1062

After migrating servers, I'm getting an error every time I try to update customer information. I'm using a [customer activation plugin](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vinai/extension/489/customer-activation#overview), but after disabling it, I still get the same error.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7-127' for key 2
```

What is wrong?

Even after uninstalling the plugin, I get this error while trying to save customer information. So this leads me to believe its a bigger problem with Magento and/or the server I'm switched to.

I checked the Magento's log and I'm getting this Notice multiple times:

```
ERR (3): User Notice: Sorry, your PCRE extension does not support UTF8 which is needed for the I18N core  in ../httpdocs/store/lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php on line 769
```

Is this relevant?

Comment: Some code in your Magento system is causing SQL to run which tries to insert data into a database column that's been declared with a unique key. The possible causes for this are legion and if you want an answer on **this** forum you'll need to put in some debugging time.

Comment: I've updated with all I found in Magento's log.

Comment: "What happens when you trace the SQL that's being run", he asked passive-aggressively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is because when you migrated your database, mysql *helpfully* restarts the id columns that are auto-increment and Magento has some hardcoded values that assume that IDs start from zero. You need to disable foreign_key_checks when you import the data.

Comment: This is a dead link. Would've been nice to have a copy-paste here for posterity....

Answer (score 1):

Your edit is attempting to re-CREATE the user, instead of UPDATE-ing the existing user. It's a bug with the plugin. You may want to report it to the author or wait for an update to come out.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to import SQL file , make sure that you “Disable foreign key checks” .
For that just add **SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;** at the start of SQL file.
Also add **SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;** at the end of file.