# My store returns no code id and breaks 404 error. Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I know what the issue is but I dont know how to fix it. I just migrated my magento store locally and I guess possibly some data may have been lost when transferring the DB. the DB is very large. Anyhow, when I login to my admin page, I get a 404 error, page was not found.

I debugged the issue and got down to the wire. The exception is thrown in Mage/Core/Model/App.php. Line 759 to be exacted. The following is a snippet.

### Mage/Core/Model/App.php

```
    if (empty($this->_stores[$id])) {
        $store = Mage::getModel('core/store');
        /* @var $store Mage_Core_Model_Store */
        if (is_numeric($id)) {
            $store->load($id); // THIS ID IS FROM Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID and its empty which causes the error
        } elseif (is_string($id)) {
            $store->load($id, 'code');
        }

        if (!$store->getCode()) { // RETURNS FALSE HERE BECAUSE NO ID Specified
            $this->throwStoreException();
        }
        $this->_stores[$store->getStoreId()] = $store;
        $this->_stores[$store->getCode()] = $store;
    }
```

The store returns null because $id is null so it therefore does not load any model which explains why it returns false when calling getCode()

[image]

[EDIT]
If you want clarification, please ask for more before voting my post down. Remember I am still trying to get help not get neglected.

I am using Version 1.4.1.1.  When I type in the URL for admin, I get a 404 page. I walked through the code thouroughly and found that the Model MAGE_CORE_MODEL_STORE::getCode(); Returns Null which triggers the exception. and ends the script. I do not have any other detail. I further troubleshooted the issue by checking the database and that is what the screen shot is. Showing that there is infact data in the Code Colunn.

So my question is why is the Model returning a empty column when the column clearly has a value. What can I do to further troubleshoot and figure out why its not working

[EDIT UPDATE NEW]

I did some research. the reason its returning NULL is because the store ID is null being passed

```
Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('web/secure/use_in_adminhtml', Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); // THIS IS THE ID being specified
```

Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID has no value in it, so this method throws the exception. Not sure why how to fix this.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, do you think your question making any sense?

Comment: Question is unanswerable with the non-details provided.

Comment: All I can say is when I try to login to the back of magento, I get a 404 page error. When I walk through the code, the exception that stops the code is due to the fact that $store (Mage_Core_Model_Store) returns no CODE id.  This is all I know. I am using Version 1.4.1.1. What else ?? The site works live, it doent locally

Comment: @numerical25: `Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID` usually is defined as `0`, but not as `null`, so `is_numeric()` should've been triggered. In standard Magento `store_id = 0` is reserved for admin purposes (e.g. backend), but your `core_store` table screenshot doesn't show any record with `store_id = 0`. Another thing coming to my mind is that you are possibly using wrong `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']` and `$_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']` settings in your local environment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the ID of the admin store, website and store_group to zero. It is due to a mysql import which didn't reset autoincrement values and Magento hard-coding the fallback store ID to zero.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103513/magento-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-on-customer-update/6107582#6107582) for more information.

Comment: +1, because this would at least explain why his `core_store` table screenshot doesn't have a record with `store_id = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post but I struggled with this exact same thing for a couple of days before figuring it out.  I am not sure if it's something to do with the way the DB was backed up but when I was trying to import a Magento 1.9.x database from a backup I was getting all kinds of issues like this.  I was able to fix the 404 by following the above steps but then there were tons of other ID's that were incremented wrong all over the DB causing all kinds of issues with products, menus, etc.  The solution was to add this at the beginning of the SQL file

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION;SET NAMES utf8;
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0; 
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO';
SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0;
```

and add this at the end of the file

```
SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT;
SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS;
SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION;
SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES;
```

prior to importing.  Once I did that, the import went fine and all ID's were as they should be.  Hope this helps someone out of a pinch as it did me.

Thanks,

Tony